# HTTPS reverse proxy using apache

Tags: ssl, proxy, http, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I am using this apache configuration to set up a reverse proxy to a process running on the same machine, on port 8443,

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
   RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Proxy>

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443/

</IfModule>
```

The process running on 8443 already has HTTPS / SSL certificate set up. Is this a valid / good configuration or can I do it better?

I noticed that currently even http:// will proxy to https:// without the rewrite kicking in. I think this might compromise SSL? I'd rather have only 443 proxy to 8443 and just use a URL rewrite to rewrite the http:// requests to https:// requests. Is that possible using apache?

Thanks.

**EDIT** - Here is the virtual host information as requested,

```
VirtualHost Configuration: 
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443       127.0.0.1 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Sounds like this is just in the global config and not in a `<VirtualHost>` block, right?  Can you add the output from `apachectl -S` to your question?

Comment: See my edit. This is global configuration in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the HTTP requests to redirect instead of proxying, you should do two things:

1. Move your proxying config (`SSLProxyEngine` through `ProxyPassReverse` into the SSL virtual host in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, so that it'll only apply there
2. Create an HTTP virtual host which will redirect - probably in a new `.conf` file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName redirect
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
   </VirtualHost>
   ```